# How to clear sections of a SharePoint online page using the new PnP PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

In a SP Online page, there are multiple sections with webparts on them. I want to totally clear them with PnP PowerShell.

So far I have

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite" -Interactive
write-host "Removing zones from home page..."

$pg = Get-PnPPage -Identity "Home"
$sectionsCount = $pg.Sections.Count
write-host "Found $($sectionsCount) zones"
for($i=$sectionsCount-1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    write-host "Removing zone $($i)"
    $pg.Sections.RemoveAt($i)
}
$page = Set-PnPPage -Identity $pg -Publish
```

When I run this, it sees the number of zones and iterates through them. But after it runs, when I refresh the page, all the sections are still there.

I am on latest version 1.7.0 PnP.PowerShell.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried applying page template?

Comment: No, what is that?

Comment: After connecting to site, you can do Get-PnPSiteTemplate to export the page template of the home page of the site you are on. Then you can do Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate. If you delete everything from the first page, then export, it should get deleted on the imported site.  See here for use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/invoke-pnpsitetemplate?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: That actually worked, thanks.

Comment: Nice. Please accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting to site, you can do Get-PnPSiteTemplate to export the page template of the home page of the site you are on. Then you can do Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate.

If you delete everything from the first page, then export, it should get deleted on the imported site. See here for use:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/invoke-pnpsitetemplate?view=sharepoint-ps